# Pine Editor tradingview

Tags: pine-script

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

`alertcondition (ma_up, title = "Buy Condition", message = "Buy Condition Alert")`

> Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 7: Undeclared identifier
> 'ma_up'

Comment: The error message tells you the problem: `ma_up` is undeclared. Do you have a variable with that name?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is saying that `ma_up` doesn't exist. If you show more of your code, we could look at where the problem is.